# In SSRS can you have data from a db2 datasource and data from a SQL datasource in the same tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to display results from a query against a DB2 datasource as well as a query from a sql data source in the same table (report).  Is this even possible?  I'm trying to compare data to see if there are errors from the sql data source which inserts data into the DB2 accounting database.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to set up a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in Sql Server to the DB2 server, and then you can join across the databases to create a single dataset for your report.